# FFMPEG - Scale video filter not providing expected results

Tags: ffmpeg, transcoding

Apologies if this question has been asked.  I couldn't find it, but if it has, please let me know and I'll close this out.

I'm attempting a simple scale of a video whose original dimensions are 480x360 and whose target dimensions are 400x300.  The video starts as an FLV and eventually needs to end up as an MPEG. I'm using the following command line to do this:

```
ffmpeg -i user.flv -vf "scale=400:300" user_scaled.mpg
```

When I play the scaled video in MPEG Streamclip, the scale is correct and the video info shows that the dimensions are 400x300.  However, when I play the scaled video in Quicktime, the video is scaled to 478x359.  More importantly, FFMPEG, itself, treats the video as being 478x359, so any future commands (trimming, conversion, overlaying, etc) executed on it result in a video of 478x359.

The initial workflow required an FLV to MPEG conversion, but I've tried this with several different in and out formats (FLV -> FLV, FLV -> MPEG, MPEG -> MPEG, etc) all with the same results. As long as I can end up with an MPEG, though, I can deal with however many steps and conversions it would take to get this scaling working.

I'll paste the command-line output below, and a sample input video is also linked below, if you'd like it.  Thank you very much for any help.

http://www.monkeydriver.com/dpassera/stack_flv.zip

**Command-line output:**

```
ffmpeg -i user.flv -vf "scale=400:300" user_scaled.mpg

ffmpeg version 0.7-rc1, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May 21 2011 22:13:19 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 
 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth
 --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions
 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC'
 --enable-avfilter --enable-libdirac --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame
 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264
 --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared
 --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
 --disable-yasm --enable-filters --enable-filter=movie

  libavutil    50. 40. 1 / 50. 40. 1
  libavcodec   52.120. 0 / 52.120. 0
  libavformat  52.108. 0 / 52.108. 0
  libavdevice  52.  4. 0 / 52.  4. 0
  libavfilter   1. 77. 0 /  1. 77. 0
  libswscale    0. 13. 0 /  0. 13. 0
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0

[flv @ 0x11dd3b30] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, flv, from 'user.flv':

  Metadata:
    duration        : 5
    videocodecid    : 2
    audiocodecid    : 6
    canSeekToEnd    : true
    createdby       : FMS 4.0
    creationdate    : Mon Oct 31 11:43:44 2011

  Duration: 00:00:04.62, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: flv, yuv420p, 640x480, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: nellymoser, 44100 Hz, mono, s16

[buffer @ 0x11ddc950] w:640 h:480 pixfmt:yuv420p

[scale @ 0x11dda610] w:640 h:480 fmt:yuv420p -> w:400 h:300 fmt:yuv420p flags:0xa0000004

[mpeg @ 0x11dd6bd0] VBV buffer size not set, muxing may fail

Output #0, mpeg, to 'user_scaled.mpg':
  Metadata:
    duration        : 5
    videocodecid    : 2
    audiocodecid    : 6
    canSeekToEnd    : true
    createdby       : FMS 4.0
    creationdate    : Mon Oct 31 11:43:44 2011
    encoder         : Lavf52.108.0

    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p, 400x300, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 60 tbc

    Stream #0.1: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s

Stream mapping:
Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Stream #0.1 -> #0.1

Press [q] to stop encoding
frame=  230 fps=  0 q=10.2 size=     366kB time=3.82 bitrate= 785.6kbits/s dup=175 drop=0 
frame=  267 fps=  0 q=10.7 Lsize=     412kB time=4.43 bitrate= 761.3kbits/s dup=203 drop=0    

video:370kB audio:36kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 1.568959%
```

Comment: That all looks right.  What's the output of `ffprobe -show_streams user_scaled.mpg`?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for looking at this. The full output is too long to paste, so I've put it in a text document at http://monkeydriver.com/docs/ffprobe_output.rtf

Here's an excerpt from the output, where dimensions are mentioned. Hope it helps:
`Input #0, mpeg, from 'user_scaled.mpg':
  ...
    Stream #0.0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p, 400x300 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 104857 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
    ...
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=mpeg1video
codec_long_name=MPEG-1 video
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=1/60
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
width=400
height=300`

Comment: That all looks correct, how about `ffprobe -show_format` (the only important output from that is the bit between the `[FORMAT]` tags, not the whole ffmpeg preamble).  You might also try throwing in an `-s 400x300` if it is a problem with the container formatting.

Comment: Sure thing.  The output is below.  I also tried `ffmpeg -i user.flv -vf "scale=400:300" -s 400x300 user_scaled_2.mpg` and `ffmpeg -i user.flv -s 400x300 user_scaled_2.mpg`, with the same results (dimensions of 478x359).

`ffprobe -show_format user_scaled.mpg

[FORMAT]

filename=user_scaled.mpg

nb_streams=2

format_name=mpeg

format_long_name=MPEG-PS format

start_time=1.000000 

duration=4.571433 

size=421888.000000 

bit_rate=738303.000000 

[/FORMAT]`

Comment: I'm baffled.  All this output looks like the scaling worked just as it should have.  Quicktime and ffmpeg are really seeing some other scale for `user_scaled.mpg`?  If you post the video, I'll try scaling it, but I don't see why what you're doing hasn't worked.

Comment: "Baffled" is an understatement.  I have a fairly good understanding of how to use FFMPEG (not much of behind the scenes obviously), and I've tried absolutely every combination of input formats, output formats, intermediary steps, etc.  It's gotta be something to do with the video starting as an FLV.  I have the FLV zipped up at here - http://www.monkeydriver.com/dpassera/stack_flv.zip.  Unfortunately, the input video will always come from a webcam and start life as an FLV on an FMS. Again, thanks immensely for the effort you've put into this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much gnashing of teeth, I think the problem has nothing to do with ffmpeg, and everything to do with **Quicktime**.

Quicktime Player (10.1 (501.5)) scales videos to match the size of the window, and has a minimum window size.  So regardless of the actual video size, Quicktime will scale it to at least 480 by 360.  This is why the info display has size information in the "Format" section (the true size), but also has a "Current Size" section.  Changing the window size changes that latter number.

So, scale videos using ffmpeg either with `-vf scale` or just `-s`, but don't trust Quicktime Player to show them to you at the correct size.  I recommend [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) as a very capable alternative.

Comment: Thank you.  So simple, but that helped me out.